# How to fix Kali Linux date problem?

Tags: kali-linux

I am using Kali Linux 2020.1 , I am constantly having problem for wrong date. I changed with date set command but it automatically changes when I reboot, how can I fix that.
Note : I tried to do it with both user account and root account.

Comment: What is the output of the command `timedatectl status` ?

Comment: You've just [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586422/how-to-fix-kali-linux-date-problem#comment1092297_586428) you're new to Linux. Please may I suggest that you don't start with Kali. It doesn't work the same way that normal Linux-based distributions work, and it's not intended to be a distribution for beginners. See https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ for Offensive Security's own take on this. Try Ubuntu, Mint, or possibly even Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

in linux look for  **System Clock uses UTC**

given your time zone and the difference in hours by which your time is always changing is how you can confirm this is the cause.

Up to you if you want to

- set your bios clock to local time and uncheck *System Clock uses UTC*,
- or if you want to set your bios clock to *coordinated universal time* and then in linux check *System Clock uses UTC*.

Comment: Actually I am new to Linux, can you explain it in easy way and list code how to do it pls.

Comment: sorry, don't know anything about kali linux so that's the best i can instruct you.  Look under whatever control panel or system settings dealing with date & time and you will likely find that setting for using UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

as @ron said

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

then choose `Etc` and `Universal`